# Deserialisation of the unicode keys in Django REST Framework 2

Tags: python, json, django, unicode, django-rest-framework

I've got my json file with the following content:

```
[
    {
      "id": "201020102",
      "lab_name": "мурмур",
      "sex": "onto",
      "species": "onto",
      "age": "24 pontakleęfmnds",
      "strain": "onto",
      "desease": "onto",
      "comment": "some string"
    }
]
```

I've written the serializer for it:

```
class SpecimenSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.CharField()
    lab_name = serializers.CharField()
    sex = serializers.CharField()
    age = serializers.CharField()
    species = serializers.CharField()

    def restore_object(self, attrs, instance=None):
        if instance:
            # TODO make it mutable
            return instance

        return m.Entity.objects.create(lab_name=self.lab_name)
```

I'm trying to deserialise my json like that:

```
testJson = json.load(open("data/specimens.json"))
specimenSerializer = SpecimenSerializer(data=testJson[0])
```

the problem is that I don't see the fields in specimenSerializer.data to be filled with values from the json file. I think it has to do something with unicode. In my case I can guarantee that the keys of the json will always be ascii, but the values can be unicode.

Comment: Have you called `serializer.is_valid()` before accessing `serializer.data`? See Validation section in [Serializers](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/)

Comment: @SamRad DRF 2 doesn't have that restriction (DRF 3 triggers a warning), though I would still recommend doing it.